# FreeRADIUS cannot bind to FreeIPA

Tags: ldap, radius, freeradius, freeipa

I have installed FreeRADIUS and FreeIPA on the same machine running Fedora 33. IPA is working as expected and can have clients join and authenticate. LDAP command line tools (ldapsearch, ldapmodify) can successfully bind to the server both locally and over the network using the same credentials.

But when I try to start radiusd (either in debug mode or as a daemon) I get the error "Server is busy". CPU and RAM usage when testing is less than 10% so I don't think the server is overloaded. Below is the LDAP instantiation log. I have tried to find a log of attempted LDAP binds but have been unsuccessful.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
> # Instantiating module "ldap" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/ldap
>     rlm_ldap: libldap vendor: OpenLDAP, version: 20450
>     accounting {
>      reference = "%{tolower:type.%{Acct-Status-Type}}"
>     }
>     post-auth {
>      reference = "."
>     }
>     rlm_ldap (ldap): Initialising connection pool
>     pool {
>      start = 5
>      min = 3
>      max = 32
>      spare = 10
>      uses = 0
>      lifetime = 0
>      cleanup_interval = 30
>      idle_timeout = 60
>      retry_delay = 30
>      spread = no
>     }
>     rlm_ldap (ldap): Opening additional connection (0), 1 of 32 pending slots used
>     rlm_ldap (ldap): Connecting to ldap://[servername hidden]:389
>     rlm_ldap (ldap): Waiting for bind result...
>     rlm_ldap (ldap): Bind with [credentials hidden] to ldap://[servername hidden]:389 failed: Server is busy
>     rlm_ldap (ldap): Opening connection failed (0)
>     rlm_ldap (ldap): Removing connection pool
>     /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/ldap[8]: Instantiation failed for module "ldap"
```